# Set an HTML attribute with a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var canvasWidth = 800;
    var canvasHeight = 600;
</script>
```

I want to use these variables to set the attributes of an HTML tag
This is not syntactically correct, but shows how I am wanting to use the variables:

```
<canvas id="context" width='canvasWidth' height='canvasHeight' style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

How might I do this? Is this even good practice? How would you recommend I control the canvas size, as well as clear the canvas using JavaScript?

Comment: `document.getElementById("context").width = canvasWidth;` also, why are you naming the canvas "context", when there is a context in relation to the canvas, which is something different?

Comment: Get a reference using get element by id, then set its width/height. Please don't ask multiple questions on one post. Separate questions are more useful to others

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this

getElementById("yourId").style.width = "300px";

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;
document.getElementById('context').width = canvasWidth;
document.getElementById('context').height = canvasHeight;
```

```html
<canvas id="context" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```